# need to know when an excel workbook window is being close

Tags: excel-addins

I am working and excel addin and I am under the need to open a new window of the same workbook to enter data in a different worksheet. For the new window, I will need to know when the window is being closed so I can do some validations on the data entered. Is there a way to know when a Workbook window is being closed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this document:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/213566

Create a Module and a Class Module. Code is below.

Class Module code:

```
Public WithEvents appevent As Application

Dim windowsCount As Integer


Private Sub appevent_WindowActivate(ByVal Wb As Workbook, ByVal Wn As Window)
If windowsCount <> Application.Windows.Count Then
    MsgBox "You closed a window"
End If
End Sub


Private Sub appevent_WindowDeactivate(ByVal Wb As Workbook, ByVal Wn As Window)
windowsCount = Application.Windows.Count
End Sub
```

Module Code:

```
Dim myobject As New Class1


Sub Test()

Set myobject.appevent = Application

End Sub
```

And this handler for the workbook:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Test
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Anderson, I will give a try to see if I can manage to get it working this way. For I have added a button to the ribbon so the user must close the window using the button instead of the X button on the window, that way I will be able to run the custom logic required. Not the ideal solution but it is all that I have been able to do so far.

Answer (score -1):

You can handle the [BeforeClose](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.beforeclose.aspx) event. An example using VBA is available [here](http://j-walk.com/ss/excel/tips/tip78.htm).

Comment: Hi Frederic, Thank you for your response. the Workbook.BeforeClose event fires only when the last workbook window is closed. What I need is to handle the Workbook window close event. So if you have Book1.xlsx:1 and Book1.xlsx:2 then I need to know when Book1.xlsx:2 is being closed.